# Switching rows of two dimensional arrays in c

Tags: c

At the moment I'm wondering how can I swap the values already in a two dimensional array, in this case I managed to swap them, however, I can't seem to be able to swap them back... How can I make a program swap the  values back and forward for the array?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    //declaration of values
    int d = 0;
    char value;
    float list[5][6], swaplist[5][6];
    float average_odd, sum = 0, average_even, sum1 = 0;

    //Command list so that the user knows what he can do in this program
    printf("Command list:\t \n\nCommand: \t\t Output: ");
    printf("\n  \"A\"  \t\t Declare values of a list.\n  \"O\"  \t\t Obtain the average value of the even and odd column\n\t\t values in the list.\n");
    printf("  \"I\"  \t\t Exchange the values on the even columns with the odd ones.\n  \"P\"  \t\t Print the values of the list.\n  \"S\"  \t\t End program.");
    //========================================================================================================
    while (d != 1)
    {
        printf("\n\nInsert value: ");
        scanf(" %c", &value);
        //=========================================================================================================
        if (value == 'a' || value == 'A')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    printf("Insert value of element %d in column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
                    scanf("%f", &list[i][j]);
                    swaplist [i][j] = list[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        //=========================================================================================================
        if (value == 's' || value == 'S')
        {
            d++;
        }
        //=========================================================================================================
        if (value == 'P' || value == 'p')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    printf("%2.2f   ", list[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        //========================================================================================================
        if (value == 'o' || value == 'O')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j = j + 2)
                {
                    sum += list[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 6; j = j + 2)
                {
                    sum1 += list[i][j];
                }
            }
            average_even = sum1 / 15;
            printf("The average of the  even columns = %.2f\n", average_even);
            average_odd = sum / 15;
            printf("The average of the odd columns = %.2f\n", average_odd);
        }
        //=======================================================================================================
        if (value == 'i' || value == 'I')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j = j + 2)
                {
                    list[i][j] = swaplist[i][j+1];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 6; j = j + 2)
                {
                    list[i][j] = swaplist[i][j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of the `main()` function is always `int`, never `void`

Comment: @user3629249 That is not true. C Standard defines main as `5.1.2.2.1. Program startup, paragraph 1: ...or in some other implementation-defined manner.`. I suggest you take a look at microcontrollers where void main is commonly used.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "swap the values back and forward"? Swapping values has no direction, it only exchanges the value, doing it twice will result in the original values.

Comment: It is a good programming practice to have only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.   This also makes it easy to document the code, for such tools as `doxygen`

Comment: @this, the C standard gives only 2 valid ways (ignoring the possible environment pointer parameter) to write the main() declaration: 1) `int main( int argc, char *argv[])`  2) `int main( void )`  and one optional way (that is expected to be removed: `int main()`.   Note `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` are the same thing.   And lets' remember that we are not programming for a 'barebones' microcontroller.  Rather we are using a compiler, such as `gcc` on a pc, with an OS.

Comment: when calling the system function `scanf()` (and related family of functions), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Some of the ';magic' numbers are: `5` `6` `15`   Suggest using #defines or an enum to give the numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the posted code has an odd number of rows `5`, numbered 0...4.  so it will be a problem to swap all the `odd` rows.  Specifically, there is no matching row for `list[4]` to swap.   However, the code seems to be trying to swap between different arrays.  However, both arrays contain exactly the same values.  However, this kind of line: `list[i][j] = swaplist[i][j+1];` is shuffling the columns between the arrays, not swapping rows

Comment: yes, my bad I meant columns , sorry for the confusion :l...

Comment: @user3629249 I guess you didn't read my comment. Instead I suggest you read the actual standard at the heading I posted. Let's remember this question is tagged only with C, and not with gcc pc or OS. In this context only the C standard is relevant as far as main() is concerned. Therefore your appeal to specific architectures and compilers is a strawman argument.( And you can look at your own comments, the second one contradicts the first one. In the second you clearly imply that there are actual cases where main is not int main(), refuting the first comment. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After swapping, you don't change the state of the swap list. At first, the swap list is a copy of the unswapped matrix. You don't change it to reflect the changes in the matrix and don't keep track of any other state.

You don't really need the swap list. I suggest that you just do a regular swapping of adjacent columns cell by cell:

```
    if (value == 'i' || value == 'I') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j = j + 2) {
                float swap = list[i][j];

                list[i][j] = list[i][j + 1];
                list[i][j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
```

That will toggle the matrix on repeated swaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I don't get why so many down votes, please let me know if it's against the rules this kind of post, I'm just trying to find the most efficient way of attacking this kind  of problem, again thanks a lot!